# Download file from server to local machine - keep original last updated date

Tags: c#, .net, file

Currently I am downloading files using httpwebrequest and response and file stream, and the last updated date of file get changes to the current date of the server. Can I prevent this?

```
using (FileStream fileStream = File.Create(@sTargetPath))
                            {
                                Sys.Log2(20, "Filestream - copying starts");
                                fileCopy(responseStream, fileStream);
                            }


public static void fileCopy(Stream input, Stream output)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[3024]; 
        int bytesRead;

        while ((bytesRead = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    }
```

Comment: So you want to prevent the modification time of the destination file (`sTargetPath`) from changing? Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the last updated date of the remote file with [`File.GetLastWriteTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5da1572(v=vs.110).aspx) and store it in e.g. `DateTime lastUpdatedDate`. Then, after closing the output stream, you can set it on your newly created file with [`File.SetLastWriteTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t467se1x(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
File.SetLastWriteTime(@sTargetpath, lastUpdatedDate);
```

EDIT:

As @HaraldDutch points out, you have to take timezones into account. In that case, `File.GetLastWriteTimeUTC` and `File.SetLastWriteTimeUTC` are safer to use.

Comment: Are you sure if you use GetLastWriteTime that the System.DateTime you get is in your time zone? After all the file is downloaded. If you use the returned value to File.SetLastWriteTime do the UTC times remain the same? Or would a European File suddenly be six hours older after downloading in the USA. And how about if you downloaded when daylight saving time starts? Wouldn't it be better to always use UTC times except when you are interfacing to humans?

Comment: where i need to put this line in the original code: File.SetLastWriteTime(@sTargetpath, lastUpdatedDate);